# Mybatis Unable to pass multiple columns from master query to association query

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Passing multiple columns from the master query to the association query doesn't work.

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'CustomerId' not found. Available parameters are []


@SelectProvider(type = CustomerProvider.class, method = "fetchAllById")
@Results({
        @Result(property="accounts",
                column="customerId, accountId",
                javaType=Account.class,
                one = @One(select="com.deeshank.dao.AccountMapper.fetchAccounts",
                        fetchType = FetchType.EAGER))
})
List<Customer> fetchAllById(CustomerQueryRequest queryRequest);
```

customerId and accountId comes from the select columsn of the master query.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the mybatis version 3.4.1 or later solved the issue.

https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/230